# Get the last 3 words from url path

Tags: php

url like this:

http://localhost/333/ed/a3

I tried like this

```
$pattern = '/(([^ ]*)\s+([^ ]*)\s+([^ ]*))$/';
preg_match($pattern, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0];
```

I get error  Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current error seems to happening because there is no zeroth match in the array.  This is because your pattern is not matching the URL.  The biggest problem I see is that your pattern insists on matching some whitespace inside the URL, which (should) never happen.

Try this version:

```
$pattern = '/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+$/';
preg_match($pattern, "http://localhost/333/ed/a3", $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0];
print_r(preg_split("/\//", $last_word));

Array
(
    [0] => 333
    [1] => ed
    [2] => a3
)
```

### Demo

Comment: is it possible to get "333", "ed", "a3" each on in array element in $matches ?

Answer (score 1):

does it have to be a regex? If so I recommend using https://regexr.com

For simplicity, I'll show how to use the built in explode function with the array slice function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
`array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php
`array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = FALSE ]] )`

*Untested* Example:

`$url = explode ( '\' , $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$last_three = array_slice ( $url, -3, 3 );`